# Checking app version on store and compare it with current version plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a phonegap application on ios store
I would like to ask If there is any plugin or javascript library
that checks the app version on ios store

For Example:
if i uploaded another version on the store , i want the application to check store version with the current version the user have. and compare those versions.
if it matches then ok , if not redirect the user to the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is currently any plugin or library for this. What you might be able to do is grab the info via the itunes link and parse it for app version.

1. Create a link to your app at https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/
2. Use an ajax call to pull in that link.
3. Parse the results for version info and do what you want with it.

Comment: Thanks I did the ajax call on the link. and from the response i got the version number. Thanks !